# How can I find the serial number of my Mac mini?

Tags: mac-mini, serial-number

Do Mac mini come with a unique serial number? How do I find it?

It is a model without optical drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a recent generation of Mac mini. They come without the Optical Drive.

To determine the serial number of your Mac mini (or any Mac for that matter), click on the  menu item in the Menu Bar, select **About This Mac**. You will see the serial number mentioned in the window that opens. This window will also specify the model and year of your Mac mini.

[image]

Alternatively, on your Mac mini, you can also spot the serial number printed on the metal frame towards the bottom of the machine. For instructions, you can refer this Apple Support Document, [Mac mini: How to find the serial number](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201173).

Device specific instructions on finding serial number of an Apple product can be found in the support article, [Find the serial number of your Apple product](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204308).

Comment: Is there any danger in sharing your serial number with strangers?

Comment: No major threats, but it's better not to divulge.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. They come with unique serial number. You can find the serial number as per Apple Support Document.

[Mac mini: How to find the serial number](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201173)

**In Mac OS X**

On most computers with Mac OS X, you can find the serial number in the About This Mac window.

[image]

**On the surface of the computer**

On Mac mini (Mid 2010 and later) computers, the serial number is printed on the metal frame without a bar code:

[image]